# How to set up node module to export type information

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm

I'm writing a node module that is the api layer for my react and react native app. I've gotten it to the point where typescript is exporting everything except for the `type` objects. As I understand it, I could create a custom typing for my project, but that seems unnecessary. Here's what my compiled `index.d.ts` file looks like

```js
import InventoryService from "./src/services/InventoryService";
import PlentiItemService from "./src/services/PlentiItemService";
...
declare type PlentiType = "Fruit" | "Decorative" | "Herb" | "Poultry" | "Vegetable" | "Unknown";
declare type QuantityName = "None" | "A Little" | "Some" | "A Lot" | "Many";
export { AccountLoginForm, AccountSignupForm, AccountUpdateForm, ..., PlentiType, QuantityName}
```

Note that the types are exported, but the don't appear to be usable in the installing application. Why is that?

Comment: Did you add your types location to your package.json?

Comment: yeah I had- turns out it was because I was using a file reference to access it as opposed to getting it via github... weird that that would be different. Ah well.

Comment: Update: it looks like even switching to GH installs, I have to navigate to the specific folder where the types are contained. It looks like barrel files(?) aren't set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the types are exported, but the don't appear to be usable in the installing application. Why is that

Assuming you have `"main" : "lib"` in your package.json (the path to the js files), You need to have `"types": "lib" in your package.json as well (the path to the .d.ts files).

If you are not getting the `.d.ts` file compiled out ensure that your `tsconfig.json` has `declaration: true`

## More

- Walkthrough on creating a library in TypeScript: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/library
- Video lesson https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-create-high-quality-npm-packages-using-typescript